# Android - XPath evaluate very slow

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath, vtd-xml

I'm using `XPath` to query my `XML-file` which has at the moment about `100KB`.

I'm iterating of an array and query for every value in the list.

**Unfortunately a single query takes about 3-4 seconds** under the debugger and slightly less with debugger disabled.

Any ideas why this is so slow? I use a `Galaxy S2` for testing.

Here's my code:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document document = builder.parse(new File(file_on_internal_sd_url)));

int size = mPrefs.getInt("no_ids", 0);
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    String id= mPrefs.getString("id_" + i, null);
    String expression = "/tag1/tag2[@id = '" + id+ "']";
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    if(nodes.getLength()>0) {
        myElements.add((Element)nodes.item(0));
    }
}
```

**Update**

When I leave out the `XPathConstants.NODESET` the evalution is done in no time but I don't get a `NodeList`. It returns an empty string instead...

Comment: Is a _single_ query taking 3-4 ms or all the ones in that loop together? What does your document look like?

Comment: One query takes about 3-4 Seconds(!). My document has one root node and lots of child nodes. No grandchildren.

Comment: Ronvcan you add a vtd-xml tag to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @nvrmnd I tried a bit around and found a way better parser:

[VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/)

Here's a [example](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/codeSample/cs1.html) from the devlopers.

But this [Tutorial](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.de/2010/08/faster-xpaths-with-vtd-xml.html) is way better...

Answer (score 1):

XPath itself is not very efficient when it comes to iterating through big XML-documents. I myself made the experience that parsing values out of a ~200kb XML-file took around 10 seconds on a low-end device.

After that I reimplemented the parser as a SAXParser and had huge performance increases of around 2 orders of magnitude. So I would propose that you try the SAXParser. It is actually not too hard to implement and there are a couple of tutorials out there.

There also exists a question on stackoverflow that deals with the topic of the various parsing methods: [SAX vs. DOM vs. XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689097/is-xpath-much-more-efficient-as-compared-to-dom-and-sax)

I also assume that the evaluation is done in no time when you don't use NodeSet because it will only look for a single node and return as soon as it has found a matching node.

**EDIT:**

Parsing the XML-document with SAX means that you iterate through it and store the sought information within objects. Take a look at this tutorial: [SAX Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)

There the author parses staff information and transforms it into objects so I guess that's exactly what you need.